# $_REQUEST/$_POST is printing an empty array for Webservice

Tags: php, ios, web-services, post

I am receiving Web Service from iOS device. But when I try to print the request that I have received I get data as empty.

Input Sent from iOS device as Service. It is sent as POST from iOS:

```
{"AccessToken"={"Mykey":"test123"}
```

Code in my PHP Page:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $value)
{
    $xml_content_array = trim($value);
}
```

What else I have tried:

```
if(empty($xml_content_array) === true)
{
    $xml_content_array = trim($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
}
```

Even $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not printing anything. Also tried the below:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Did not work.
I am pretty sure the data is coming from the iOS end but I am unable to capture the POST request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check http://jsonlint.com/, Not a valid json

Comment: Even with a valid json that is not working. {"Mykey":"test123"} this won't work. Also iOS sends the data in the above format itself

Comment: check you are posting on correct path, Then `file_get_contents('php://input');` will work for you

Comment: Yes path is correct.

Comment: post your iOS code as well.

Comment: did you print $_POST

Comment: Yes I have. Even that seems to be not working

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 $access_token =   $_POST["AccessToken"];
  echo $access_token;
```